# I've got an "invalid syntax" error with this code in python. Help me find a remedy?

Tags: python

In the `def(pentagon):` chunk I've named a variable "`first`". However, this causes an "invalid syntax" error. What's wrong? I've tried naming it other things, ranging from single letters to combinations of lower/capital letters like "preArea".

```
def display():
    print('This program will tell you the area some shapes')
    print('You can choose between...')
    print('1. rectangle    2. triangle')
    print('3. circle       4. pentagon')
    print('5. rhombus      6. trapezoid')

def shape():
    shape = int(input('What shape do you choose?'))
    if shape == 1: rectangle()
    elif shape == 2: triangle()
    elif shape == 3: circle()
    elif shape == 4: pentagon()
    elif shape == 5: rhombus()
    elif shape == 6: trapezoid()
    else:
        print('ERROR: select 1 2 3 4 5 or 6')
        shape()


def rectangle():
    l = int(input('What is the length?'))
    w = int(input('What is the width?'))
    areaR=l*w
    print('The area is...')
    print(areaR)


def triangle():
    b = int(input('What is the base?'))
    h = int(input('What is the height?'))
    first=b*h
    areaT=.5*first
    print('The area is...')
    print(areaT)


def circle():
    r = int(input('What is the radius?'))
    preCircle = r**2
    areaC = 3.14*preCircle
    print('The area is...')
    print(areaC)


def pentagon():
    s = int(input('What is the side length')
    first = s**2
    areaP = 1.72*first
    print('The area is...')
    print(areaP)


def rhombus():
    b = int(input('What is the base?')
    h = int(input('What is the height?')
    areaR = b*h
    print('The area is...')
    print(areaR)


def trapezoid():
    baseOne = int(input('What is the first base?')
    baseTwo = int(input('What is the second base?')
    h = int(input('What is the height')
    first = baseOne*baseTwo
    second = first/2
    areaT = second*h
    print('The area is...')
    print(areaT)


if __name__=="__main__":
    display() 
    shape()
```

Comment: Since others answered your question, maybe you would like to consider changing `shape()` function to use dictionary and its `.get()` method instead of lengthy `if ... elif ... else ...` statements? By the way it may help you avoid another obstacle: the `shape()` function being overridden by local `shape` variable.

Comment: Maybe this will give you some progress with the above mentioned issue: http://ideone.com/p73xL

Comment: Don't mark the question's title with [SOLVED], instead accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
s = int(input('What is the side length')
```

is missing a closing paren.  Programming requires paying attention to many many details...

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that that also happens in other chunks too.

Answer (score 3):

```
 s = int(input('What is the side length')
```

You are missing a closing `)`

In fact I noticed that your other `input` statements in `rhombus`, `pentagon` and `trapezoid`  have a similar problem, you probably copied code :)

You might want to use an editor that will help you match open and closing parenthesis. It will help avoid these sort of errors.

Answer (score 2):

closing parentheses is missing: `s = int(input('What is the side length'))`

Answer (score 0):

Closing parentheses is missing in these lines:

in function pentagon()

```
s = int(input('What is the side length')
```

in function rhombus()

```
b = int(input('What is the base?')
h = int(input('What is the height?')
```

in function trapezoid()

```
baseOne = int(input('What is the first base?')
baseTwo = int(input('What is the second base?')
h = int(input('What is the height')
```